# Draw a rotated element on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to draw a semi-complex element on a canvas rotated without rotating the canvas so that I don't need to calculate all of the various x/y points of the element.

I think that the basic process I need to use is:

- translate the 0,0 point to the spot the drawn element will be rotated around,
- rotate the canvas,
- draw the element,
- rotate the canvas back,
- restore the origin point.

I will need to do this more than once. I've read that the rotate / rotate back part can introduce some error, with the final image being off just a bit. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: We need code. Make a good attempt and come here when you get stuck.

Comment: I'd have a look into `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` - they don't save/restore the pixels, but rather the internal state. The transformation matrix is one of the things affected. :) For more, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#A_save_and_restore_canvas_state_example

Comment: You haven't given us enough context to help you. Give us more info or some code! But in general the html5 canvas workflow is: draw something, erase the canvas, calculate new positions, redraw the somethings in their new positions. Your theory about rotating  something is about right: translate to rotation point, rotate, draw something (usually with an offset), unrotate, untranslated. If you need to rotate repeatedly, you can put the transformation commands inside a function for easy reuse.

Comment: @markE : you're right, but 1) i guess you mean : first erase the canvas, then... and 2) saving the context, translating+rotating, then drawing and lastly restoring the context seems to me a simpler way for a beginner.

Comment: Rq : 1) draw the element... yes ! at (-ImageWidth/2, -ImageHeight/2) for an image . 2) if you're worried about numerical stability, as quoted above by @enhzsflep, save and restore are your friends. Extra bonus being you get a simpler code.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Agreed, `.save` / `.restore` are useful. When teaching beginners, I like to show the "full answer" so they can see that whatever transforms you do you must undo those same transforms in reverse order. Then they can go on to learn/use save/restore and setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) as shortcuts. ;-)

Comment: @markE : my bet is that [ a) saving b) doing any transform c) drawing d) restoring ] is the simplest way, but i fear both of us are too fluent in canvas drawing to even be able to tell which way is 'simpler' -everything is simple, just rtfm and decide-  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you perform the rotation and translation, call `context.save()`. This will create a snapshot of the current transformation of the canvas (as well as some other things, like drawing style, clip region, etc., but not the pixel data) and store it on a stack.

After you drew the shape, call `context.restore()`. This will pop the last saved state from the state stack and restore the current drawing state of the canvas to it.

You can do this as often as you want without accumulating any rounding differences.

Example function:

```
function drawImageRotated(x, y, rotation, image) {
    context.save();

    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(rotation);
    context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);        

    context.restore();

    // context translation and rotation are now on the same state they were
    // before the function call
}
```

For more information about the canvas state, refer to [the canvas specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-state).