# Image rotation without rotating the entire object

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, image-rotation, drawimage

I create a collage editor where rectangles appear at the beginning. Adds an image to rectangles that has the same parameters as the rectangle.
This is my first project using canvas.

Is it possible to rotate the SX SY photo into a function `context.ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`, without using the function `rotate()`? I would like them to be in the same position as at the start.

When I use rotation, it finds the center perfectly, but the entire orientation of the object changes as well.

elem is the canvas.
Element is the starting rectangle.
element.sx, element.sy are equal to 0 and change when the mouse is moved.

[image]

```
function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
  // Render elements.
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = element.image;

    context.save();
    context.filter = 'drop-shadow(-5px 9px 3px black) blur(2px)';

    context.fillStyle = element.colour;
    context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
    context.restore();

    if (img.src != '') {
      var scale = Math.max(element.width / img.width, element.height / img.height);
      scale += element.additionalScale;

      context.drawImage(img, element.sx, element.sy, element.width, element.height, element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);

      context.save();
      if (element.blackWhite == true) {
        var gray_scale = 'grayscale(100%)';
      } else {
        var gray_scale = 'grayscale(0%)';
      }
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ROTATION
      context.filter = 'brightness(' + element.brightness + ') ' + gray_scale + ' contrast(' + element.contrast + ')';
      context.translate(element.left + (element.width / 2), element.top + (element.height / 2));
      context.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
      context.translate(-(element.left + (element.width / 2)), -(element.top + (element.height / 2)));
      context.drawImage(img, element.sx, element.sy, element.width / scale, element.height / scale, element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);

      context.restore();
      ///////////  ADDITIONAL LINES

      if (mouse_down == true && current_photo == elements.indexOf(element)) {
        context.save();
        context.filter = 'blur(4px)';

        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = '#00008b'; // some color/style
        context.lineWidth = 0.5; // thickness

        context.strokeRect(element.left - (element.sx * scale), element.top - (element.sy * scale), img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
        context.restore();
      }
    }

    if (current_photo == elements.indexOf(element)) {
      context.save();
      context.filter = 'blur(1px) opacity(25%)';

      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = '#ff6600' // color
      context.lineWidth = 2; // thickness

      context.strokeRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
      context.restore();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Try to visualize it as if you're drawing on a piece of paper. You draw a shape. Then you want to draw a shape on its side, so you rotate your paper and draw your shape. Your paper is now still rotated, so everything you draw from here is on its side. Same goes for your canvas; it rotates the entire context (paper). All you got to do is rotate it back after you've drawn that last shape on its side and your context has been restored to normal, resulting in all shapes drawn from this point are upright.

Comment: The code seems overly complex for the problem at hand--you want to draw something rotated, it could be a `fillRect` for simplicity and change it to an image later, or use placeholder images to create a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [mcve]. Is there a reason not to use `rotate()`? This is _the_ function you use to rotate something on the canvas, as Emiel described. If you don't mind changing that requirement, try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551022/6243352).